# Filtrar un arreglo de ids en c# opciones

Tags: c#

Como puedo buscar varios ids en un array de usuarios

Por ejemplo:

Tengo este array de numeros `[10,22,34,55];`

Y tengo una lista de usuarios, es un arreglo que tiene varios objetos:

```
[
  { id: 1, name: John },
  { id: 10, name: Mike },
  { id: 12, name: Dwee },
  { id: 22, name: Jesus },
  { id: 30, name: July },
  { id: 34, name: Juan },
  { id: 36, name: Lusy },
  { id: 55, name: Susy },
  { id: 59, name: Dani },
]
```

Entonces como puedo obtener los nombres del siguiente arreglo `[10,22,34,55];` es decir como puedo filtrarlo, tenia pensado hacerlo con un foreach, y comparar los valores, pero no se si haya una forma más compacta de hacer quiza aplicar un Where o Select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Select` crea una nueva lista haciendo una transformación a cada elemento. Si vienes de javascript, es muy similar a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Puedes poner los ids en una lista y con [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) filtrar los elementos de en base a si el id de la persona se encuentra en la lista.

Cabe mencionar que la notación que usas corresponde a JSON. En C# usas llaves para escribir una lista.

En fin, creas una estructura para ayudarte y obtienes un código como este:

```
struct Person{
    public int id;
    public string name;
}

var lista = new List<Person>{
    new Person{ id= 1, name= "John" },
    new Person{ id= 10, name= "Mike" },
    new Person{ id= 12, name= "Dwee" },
    new Person{ id= 22, name= "Jesus" },
    new Person{ id= 30, name= "July" },
    new Person{ id= 34, name= "Juan" },
    new Person{ id= 36, name= "Lucy" },
    new Person{ id= 55, name= "Susy" },
    new Person{ id= 59, name= "Dani" },
};
        
int[] ids = { 10, 22, 34, 55 };
var personasFiltradasPorId = lista.Where(persona => ids.Contains(persona.id));

// Para recorrer la lista resultante puedes usar un foreach.
foreach (var persona in personasFiltradasPorId){
    Console.WriteLine(persona.name);
}
```

Comment: Me sirvio, aúnque lo ajuste con un foreach creo que si era algo necesario, gracias!